# pop-up notifications not showing when using xchat

Tags: notification, irc, xchat

I use xchat for irc, and by default, xchat doesn't show pop-up notifications (unlike *growl* in Mac, which shows pop-up notifications) whenever something is posted on the message box.   Is there a way to show these notifications, or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using xchat or xchat-gnome?  If you are using xchat-gnome then you should get on screen notifications.  You can check by going to Edit > Preferences > Scripts and Plugins > and checking that the "On-screen display" plugin is there and enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it make it work for me: http://roman-ivanov.blogspot.com/2013/03/xchat-integration-with-unity.html , but it started blinking, do not find way to make notification balloons with message.